# How to Check and Access a Python Pandas Series and the Dataframe it's connected to?

Tags: python, pandas

How to Check and Access a Python Pandas Series and the Dataframe it's connected to? For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
my_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=(6, 4)),
    index=list('abcdef'),
    columns=list('ABCD')
)

col_list = [my_df['B'],my_df['A']]
def zero_multiplier(col_name):
    x = col_name*100
    my_df[x.name] = x

for col in col_list:
    zero_multiplier(col)
print(my_df)
```

Within the for loop, x.name allows us to access the current column name we're iterating over, is there a similar Series method that tells us the Dataframe name?

Comment: What do you mean by "dataframe name"? The name of the variable it's stored to?

Comment: So there's a list of dataframes and you want to iterate over them?

Comment: yes there's a list of dataframes and you want to iterate over them